# (Win32 API - C++) RegisterClass returns error code 0

Tags: c++, winapi

`RegisterClassA()` function returns error code `0`, tried using `RegisterClassEx()` and `RegisterClass()`, It used to work perfectly today I woke up and all of a sudden this happened, I don't think there is something wrong with my code, tell me how i can fix this.

```
#include "Window.h"
using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wparam, lparam);
}

Window::Window() {
    WNDCLASSA wndclass;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = "Tejas Tawade";
    wndclass.hInstance = hinstance;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    // wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    // wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    if (!RegisterClassA(&wndclass)) {
        MessageBoxA(nullptr, "HELL", "ERROR", 1);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowA(
        "Tejas Tawade",
        "WINDOW",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        100, 100, 1000, 600,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        hinstance,
        nullptr
    );

    ShowWindow(hwnd, 1);
}

Window::~Window() {
    UnregisterClassA("HELLO", hinstance);
}

bool Window::run() {
    MSG msg;
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            return false;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You probably switched from a release configuration to a debug configuration. The latter makes sure that bugs due to uninitialized data are caught early on. You'll want to initialize **all** variables prior to use, e.g. `WNDCLASSA wndclass{};`. As an aside: There's literally no reason why your message loop actively spins. Just call `GetMessage` and your thread can go to sleep as long as there aren't any messages that require dispatching.

Comment: Are you compiling in UNICODE?
Use RegisterClass instead of Uses RegisterClassA.
Same for CreateWindow, MessageBox...

Comment: @CGi03 Suggesting to use generic-text mappings in 2022 is straight up malicious. There's nothing technically wrong with the `RegisterClassA` call, irrespective of preprocessor macros. The only issue that the code doesn't go all the way. Especially the call to `DefWindowProc` might choke, but that happens long after the `RegisterClassA` call (see [It’s okay to be contrary, but you need to be consistently contrary: Going against the ambient character set](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211210-00/?p=106021) for details).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initialize all the members present in `WNDCLASS`, especially `hbrBackground` and `lpszMenuName`, otherwise they become wild pointers. And for the extra memory size `cbClsExtra` and `cbWndExtra`, they should be 0 if not used. You can check [the document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes?source=recommendations#extra-class-memory) for detailed information and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-window-classes) for example code.
Besides, the class name provided in `UnregisterClassA` is not consistent with what you register. If you delete the window and create it again, it will fail because the window class already exists.

Comment: *"If you delete the window and create it again, it will fail"* - No, it won't. Since the window class never actually was unregistered, creating future window instances will succeed. The real advice here should be not to unregister window classes at all unless you have a very specific requirement (I can't think of one).

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, window creating will succeed *in asker's code*, but I mean future `RegisterClassA` will fail as you can't re-register existing window classes (I've just tested that). Normally initialization should be aborted as class registration has failed, not just popping a message box.

Comment: @IInspectable But I do agree there's no need to unregister window classes unless it's a dynamic library project.

Comment: Even in a DLL project that's not required. The code doesn't use the [`CS_GLOBALCLASS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-class-styles) flag, so the window class is local to the implementing module. Another module can register a local window class with the same name just fine. [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873) explains how the system works.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your help, as you guys told me I have to "INITIALIZE A FEW THINGS" i figured i need to initialize wndclass = {}, hwnd = nullptr, hinstance = nullptr and msg = {}. this made my window work perfectly.

Comment: @Tejas Well, if you think the comments or the answer here did solve your problem, you can do as [what should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)